# YouTubePlayerFragment not able to change video quality

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am using `YoutubePlayerFragment` for playing of `Youtube` videos. The videos are running fine, but when I try to change video quality, the video quality is not changing and retaining the old quality.

When I tried it with the 'youtube sample' that is provided by Google the same issue is reproducible.

The same issue is logged in https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8558&q=YouTubePlayerFragment%20not%20able%20to%20change%20video%20quality&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

Comment: for me its not showing on kitkat but its showing in marshmallow!

Comment: @SohailZahid I m using Android 5.1 with Moto E. Do you have any idea?

Comment: have you try on different videos?

Comment: Same issue is reproducible for other videos.